# Swift Unable to store JSON String as Date

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an `NSManagedObject` Subclass that has a `dateOfBirth` field in it.

```
@NSManaged var dateOfBirth: NSDate
```

Elsewhere, I am downloading a load of JSON strings and I need to fill my `dateOfBirth` field with the downloaded JSON version. I thought I had this figured, but later when I went to use the value it wsa nil, even though the value I was getting returned from the JSON was there.

Since then I've tried all sorts of incantations to try and get the thing to save.

```
 //This is my latest 'attempt', trying to downcast the value to NSDate, it fails, originally i was just getting the .string value and converting it to a date
 if let dateOfBirth = object["json"]["dateOfBirth"].stringValue as? NSDate{

  //I actually had this formatter near the top of the function but thought perhaps it wasn't saving because the formatter was inaccessible or something?

            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"

//This value returns correctly
            println("dateOfBirth? : \(dateOfBirth)")
            newSurveyObj.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth

//This returns a nil for the dateOfBirth
            println("newSurveyObj? : \(newSurveyObj.dateOfBirth)")
        }
```

The weird thing is, I can store dates in a similar fashion elsewhere in the app,

for example this:

```
if let createdDate = object["createdDate"].string
    {

        newWorkObj.createdDate = formatter.dateFromString(createdDate)!
    }
```

works, with this being its `NSManagedObject` Sub Class:

```
    @NSManaged var createdDate: NSDate
```

Does anybody have any ideas why my dateOfBirth wont save?

edit: The output I am getting for this:

```
 if let dateOfBirth = object["json"]["dateOfBirth"].string{

                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
                println("dateOfBirth? : \(dateOfBirth)")
                newEcoObj.dateOfBirth = formatter.dateFromString(dateOfBirth)!
                println("newSurveyObj? : \(newSurveyObj.dateOfBirth)")
            }
```

is this:

```
dateOfBirth? : 1995-01-01T00:00:00
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

However, when I declare the dateOfBirth as optional, I get this output:

```
dateOfBirth? : 1995-01-01T00:00:00
newSurveyObj? : nil for Street name
```

Comment: `println("dateOfBirth? : \(dateOfBirth)")` What does it shows? You don't seems to use the `formatter`.

Comment: ah, I was using the formatter, but in my attempts to figure out what was going on I removed it....I'll update the question with some output hang on.

Comment: Remove `.SSS` from the `dateFormat`?`

Comment: yesss! this was it! post it as an answer and i'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dateFormat` of the `NSDateFormatter` (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`) doesn't match string you get `1995-01-01T00:00:00`.

You need to remove the extra `.SSS` => `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` to have a match.

Comment: Except that won't match a string 1995-01-01T00:00:00.001 for example. What you actually need to do is have two NSDateFormatters and try them both. And then you add a category to NSDictionary that reads a date from a JSON dictionary unless you love duplicating the same code all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the if statement expression always return false?

```
object["json"]["dateOfBirth"].stringValue as? NSDate
```

You are specifically getting a string and then try to cast it to an NSDate. Pretty sure that will always fail.

In your other example you are specifically parsing the string to a date when you set it

Comment: If you read my comments I mentioned this was from a latest attempt at getting it to work, the following example if let createdDate = object["createdDate"].string was how my dateOfBirth was originally

Comment: Looks like you are parsing ISO 8601 date times. Something I am actually messing with currently myself (although my problems are in Java right now). Annoyingly it seems there are few implementations of parsers that actually work with all permutations of them. And your specific formatter string has the optional milliseconds part that the time stamp does not. I'd suggest you look for something that handles the entire format if you are not in control of where the data comes from